# Write a program to display all the anagrams for "abcdef" in Python

Tags: python, anagram

My friend wrote a code to display all anagrams for "abcdef" in python. But in this code, I couldn't understand how the recursive procedure works       `anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))` How does the function call itself?

```
def get_list_of_anagrams(s):
    if len(s)==0:
        return ['']
    all_chars = list(s)
    unique_chars = list(set(s))
    anagrams_list = []
    for char in unique_chars:
        tmp_list = list(all_chars)
        tmp_list.remove(char)
        anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))
        for i in range(len(anagrams)):
            anagrams[i] = char+anagrams[i]
        anagrams_list += anagrams
    return anagrams_list
```

When I try to print every thing till `anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list)`

```
def get_list_of_anagrams(s):
    if len(s)==0:
        return ['']
    all_chars = list(s)
    unique_chars = list(set(s))
    anagrams_list = []
    for char in unique_chars:
        tmp_list = list(all_chars)
        tmp_list.remove(char)
        anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))



print get_list_of_anagrams('abc')
```

I get the following out put.

[image]

For the following code:

```
def get_list_of_anagrams(s):
    if len(s)==0:
        return ['']
    all_chars = list(s)
    unique_chars = list(set(s))
    anagrams_list = []
    for char in unique_chars:
        tmp_list = list(all_chars)
        tmp_list.remove(char)
        anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))
        print anagrams
        for i in range(len(anagrams)):
            anagrams[i] = char+anagrams[i]
        anagrams_list += anagrams
    return anagrams_list  

print get_list_of_anagrams('abc')
```

I get the following output:

[image]

can some one explain me why the above output is of this pattern?

Comment: in your function , you get an empty list because it only `return['']` compared to your friend wrote `return ['']` and `return anagram_list `. to understanding a recursive function , try to find the exit (the `return`) and trace it from there

Comment: `for i in range(len(anagrams)):`  But isnt the len(anagrams) empty?? . because When I print anagrams then I get a list of empty lists . Then how come in the code My friend has looped over len(anagrams), its just empty right?

Comment: put this command  `print anagrams` after `anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))` in your friend code. it'll show you how recursion works

Comment: @whale_steward ok I will try this one

Comment: @whale_steward - I tried your suggestion. but after each iteration I am getting an empty list [''] and then a  word. This is the part I am confused how recursion is being implemented in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Life is short use libraries:

```
import itertools
d = 'abc'
e = len(d)
j = list()

for p in itertools.permutations(d, e):
    print p

('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Tracing through:

```
def get_list_of_anagrams(s):
    # base case - empty string, return empty
    if len(s)==0:
        return ['']

    # figure out which characters are available
    all_chars    = list(s)       # may have repeats
    unique_chars = list(set(s))  # no repeats

    # prepare to store all results
    anagrams_list = []

    # for each unique character
    for char in unique_chars:
        # remaining unused characters
        tmp_list = list(all_chars)
        tmp_list.remove(char)

        # recurse: get all anagrams of remaining characters
        anagrams = get_list_of_anagrams(''.join(tmp_list))

        # prefix each result with picked character
        for i in range(len(anagrams)):
            anagrams[i] = char+anagrams[i]

        # add to overall results
        anagrams_list += anagrams

    # return all results
    return anagrams_list
```

I would rewrite it a bit, like

```
def get_list_of_anagrams(s):
    anagrams = []

    remaining = list(s)
    for char in sorted(set(s)):
        remaining.remove(char)
        if remaining:
            # recurse: get all anagrams of remaining characters
            for anagram in get_list_of_anagrams(remaining):
                # prefix each result with picked character
                anagrams.append(char + anagram)
        else:
            anagrams.append(char)
        remaining.append(char)

    # return all results
    return anagrams
```

So to find `get_list_of_anagrams("abcdef")`, you get

```
"a" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("bcdef"))
"b" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("acdef"))
"c" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("abdef"))
"d" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("abcef"))
"e" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("abcdf"))
"f" + each(get_list_of_anagrams("abcde"))
```

etc.

Comment: I understood everything except the recursion part. for eg, in fibonacci The recursion is explained (https://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~fire/dev-2008f-12/labs/lab8-Recursion-vs-Iteration/fib_5.png) . is there a similar logic for the recursive function in this problem as well?

Comment: Your solution is great  up votes :) . Is it possible to write this function without using recursion.I know this is off topic, but it would be great if you could help me with this.

Comment: I think it could be written as an iterative algorithm - Knuth's permutation algorithm with slight modifications to prevent same-letter repeats (ie "abcb" should only be returned once). Actually Knuth probably includes exactly that, you'd have to check. Basically it involves repeatedly rearranging a list of the letters according to a set of rules - see the source of `itertools.permutations` for an example. It is quite a bit faster (but also significantly harder to understand) than the recursive solution.

Comment: Ok sure I will have a look at the itertools.permutations.

Comment: after each iteration I am getting an empty list [''] and then a word. This is the part I am confused how recursion is being implemented in this scenario. could you explain this thing to me?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Recursive function.
For example the famous Fibonacci Sequence:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
print fib(10)
```

Check [this question about recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence-in-python) for more information.

Comment: I know it is a recursive function. But I dont understand how it is being applied in this context.

Comment: I am tempted to change the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733761/write-a-program-to-display-all-the-anagrams-for-abcdef-in-python to make it a truly recursive definition ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, to find the anagrams of `'abc'`, first find all the anagrams of `'bc'`, which is done by first finding all anagrams of `'c'`, which is done by first finding all anagrams of `''`.

So how do you find the anagrams of the "outer layer" given all the anagrams of the "inner layer"? Given all the anagrams of `'bc'` (which are `'bc'` and `'cb'`), you can find all the anagrams of `'abc'` by inserting `a` into each positions of `'bc'` and `'cb'`. In details:

```
# 'bc' will give these anagrams:
abc # insert 'a' at first position
bac # insert 'a' at second position
bca # insert 'a' at third position (also last)

# Similarly, 'cb' gives:
acb
cab
cba
```

So 2 anagrams of `'bc'` give you 6 anagrams of `'abc'`.

===

About your algorithm: it removes 1 character at each recursion (using `tmp_list.remove(char)`). At the base case where `len(s)==0` (i.e. when all characters have been removed), it simply returns `''`. Then proceeds to find the anagrams of `'f'` using the logic above, then the anagrams of `'ef'`.... and finally returns you the anagrams of `abcdef`.

Comment: Hi Huy, I have updated the question. I was able to understand the porgram 50 % through your explanation. But I couldnt understand why am I getting a pattern like that.